# Compute the integral of a gaussian-like function

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X$ be a random variable and $\;f_X(x)=c6^{-x^2}\;\forall x\in\Bbb R$ its pdf. What I'm trying to compute is $\sqrt {Var(X)}$. I've got that $c=\sqrt{\frac{\ln(6)}{\pi}}$ for $f_X(x)$ to be a pdf and also that $\Bbb E(X)=0$. So my problem reduces to compute $\Bbb E(X^2)$ where

$$\Bbb E(X^2)=\sqrt{\frac{\ln(6)}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2\ln(6)}dx$$

but I got stuck since I can't manage to make a variable change such that leaves some constant term multiplied by integral of a $N(0,1)$ random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $y = x\sqrt{\ln(6)}$, then compare the integral to the Variance of a $N(0,1)$-variable.

Comment: Thanks! Got it! It leaves me with $\frac{1}{ln(36)}$ multiplied by the variance of a $N(0,1)$-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing an integral. Your random variable $X$ has a normal distribution, with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ to be determined. Write the density in the form
$$
6^{-x^2}=e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}
$$
(We omit the constants of proportionality, since they must be equal.) Take logs of both sides, and solve for $\sigma^2=1/\ln(36)$.